# Power BI: Transforming list of lists to table

Tags: powerbi

From an HTTP request I get a list, and each cell contains a value and a timestamp. I Would like to transform this list into a table with the columns ´time´ and ´value´. How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried expanding it in PowerQuery?

[image]